# Image Control is not rendering in WinRT 8.1 Xamarin.Forms (Portable) project

Tags: image, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library, renderer, shared-project

Image Renderer in xamarin.forms not rendering in Xamarin.Forms (Portable) and it is working in Xamarin.Forms (Shared) for windows RT 8.1 phone. Why is that so? Is there another way of rendering IMAGE control in windows RT 8.1 phone.

My code :
-assembly code here

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Image), typeof(ImageWinRenderer))]

-renderer class below

public class ImageWinRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT.ImageRenderer

- override onelement changed method

protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs e)

Comment: please add your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried working with Image render in shared project (xamarin), it worked!!. Still, not able to find conclusive answer for why it is not working in portable project